# Turning Python Object into a JSON string

Tags: python, json

I have been working on this bot that takes the twitter api and brings it into my database. Before I was grabbing 1 tweet at a time which wasn't efficient considering I was using 1 request out of the limit they had. So instead I decided to grab 150 results. I get these results back:

`[Status(ID=780587171757625344, ScreenName=Ampsx, Created=Tue Sep 27 01:57:39 +0000 2016, Text='You know who you are #memes').`

I get about 150 of these. Is there a library where I can turn this into JSON?

Comment: I don't get it. doesn't the twitter api already returns json?

Comment: you can use json module `import json` and then convert by `jsondata = json.dumps(python list or dictionary)`. therefore `Status` object should be converted to dictionary.

Comment: You can't "turn this into a JSON file". You can turn it into JSON data though.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @njzk2. I am using the python-twitter module. Which converts it to this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 2.6+ there's a bundled library you can use ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html)), just:

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps(object)
```

We use this a lot for quick API endpoints, you just need to be careful about having functions or complex nesting in the objects you're trying to serialize, it's quite configurable (so you can skip fields, customize output of some, etc.) but can get messy pretty quickly.

Comment: Using this method doesn't turn it into JSON data. Should I throw it in a for loop?

Comment: You could, but you'd end up with a series of JSON strings, you probably want to wrap them first then make a single json.dumps call

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a quick Google search would have revealed the [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) module.

```
import json

# instead of an empty list, create a list of dict objects 
# representing the statues as you'd like to see them in JSON.
statuses = { 'statuses': [] } 

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(statuses).encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
jsondata = json.dumps(TwitterStatusObject.__dict__)
```

Comment: Um no. `Object.__dict__` will return attributes and functions of the class or module.